# Crash report not created

Tags: ios

My app doesn't create a crash report for the following crash:

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [NSMutableArray new];
[arr addObject:nil];
```

What may cause my app to not create a crash report?

Update:
Found what caused the crash to not be created. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my project I had `@try @catch` in `main.m`, which caused the crash to not be created.